# Change the FK column name in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I have 2 POCO classes in EF

```
  public class Product
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public String Name { get; set; }
      public Category Category { get; set; }
  }

    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to change the "Product.Category" column name in the database.
By default EF makes it like "`Category_Id`"

I need to change it to "`Cat`". How Can I do that ? Preferably with Fluent API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.Category)  // or HasRequired
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("Cat"));
```